# Meaning of get generic method in hibernate

Tags: java, generics, jpa

Seeing this method definition:

```
<Y> Path<Y> get(String attributeName);
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.java?av=h#122

how you can describe in plain words what this method is doing?

Any official documentation about such generic syntax?

Comment: This method is in JPA API, not in Hibernate!

Answer (score 0):

I think [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) sums it up well with this example:

```
public static <Type> Entry<Type, Type> twice(Type value) {
    return new Entry<Type, Type>(value, value);
}
```

> Note: If we remove the first  in the above method, we will get compilation error (cannot find symbol 'Type') since it represents the declaration of the symbol.

In the method signature you cite, the first `<Y>` is the declaration of the type.  Most likely, if it were removed the compiler would not be able to infer what type it is.

Comment: Ok. It is a "generic method definition" It sets a contract on Objects used by method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen. I think is one explains better the idea, but both are valid

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html